# $\lim_{n \to \infty}({ \int_{0}^{1}{f_n(x)\,dx}) }=0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}({ \int_{0}^{1}{exp((f_n(x))\,dx)} }=0$ are true?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence

Question : $Let\space$ {$ \space { f_n : [0,1] \to R }\space  $}${_{n=1}^{\infty}}$ be a sequence of non- negative continuous functions such that $f_n(1)=1$.

Statement 1 : Then, it is possible that $\lim_{n \to \infty}({ \int_{0}^{1}{f_n(x)\,dx}) }=0$

Statement 2 : Then, it is possible that $\lim_{n \to \infty}({ \int_{0}^{1}{exp((f_n(x))\,dx)} }=0$

Which of the following is the true answer ?

1.) both statements

2.) statement 1

3.) statement 2

4.) none of the statements

**approach, For statement 1 :**

Suppose $f_n(x) = x^n$

**Case 1 :** when x = 1

$f_n(1)=(1)^n= 1 $.

**Thus,** $f_1(x)=f_2(x)=f_3(x).... = 1$

$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)=1$ as $n\to \infty$

**Case 2 :** for all $ x \in [0,1)$

$|x|< 1$,

$\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n = 0,$ so $f_n(x) = x^n \to 0$  as  $n \to \infty$

**Conclusion :**
$\lim_{n \to \infty}({ \int_{0}^{1}{f_n(x)\,dx}) }= \lim_{n \to \infty}({ \int_{0}^{1}{x^n\,dx}) }$ = $\lim_{n \to \infty} [\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}]_{0}^{1}$= $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n+1}=0$

**approach for statement 2 :**

As $\space e^{f_n(x)} \ge 1$ ; it can be written that $\space\space \lim_{n \to \infty}({ \int_{0}^{1}{exp((f_n(x))\,dx)} }\ge\space\space \lim_{n \to \infty}({ \int_{0}^{1}{1\,dx}) } = 1$. **Cant not equal zero** .

**My final answer**  : statement 1 is the only correct .

I wanted to confirm whether the approach is correct or not? And the answer?. Please clarify

Comment: Please, if someone could go through the solution and check.

Comment: Your proofs are correct for both cases.

Comment: @Gono very thankful for the reply. Also is my working for statement 2 correct ?

Comment: Yeah… that's what I meant with "cases". Sorry for the confusion. Should have written "statements".

Comment: @gono right, understood. Thanks!